# jquery event that run when mouse hover from child to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this simple code to understand how it works:

```
<div title="1">
    one
    <p title="2">two</p>
</div>
<br />
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    //$("body").on("mouseover","*",function(){
    //$("body").on("mouseenter","*",function(){
        var html = $(this).attr("title");
        console.log(html);
        $("#result").text(html);
    //});
});
</script>
```

When I use `mouseover`, the problem is that when I point to `two`, the event listener will first fire on `two` and then on `one`, so the effect will be like I pointed to `one`.

On the other hand, if I use `mouseenter`, the problem appears if I point to `two` without pointing to `one`, the effect will be `one`.
And if I point to `one`, then to `two`, and then to `one` again, there will be no effect at all because `two` is part of `one` so js sees that I'm still in `one` and won't work.

Is there any solution to this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is due to event bubbling, you can refer for solution

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Also you can use global flag variables to detect events

Comment: this will work with `mouseover` only so now it's work fine thanks

Comment: and i need too to understand the other solution `global flag variables` if U can

Comment: Sure define a variable flag, and on parent mouse over function set flag's value as parent and on child mouseover set flag's value as child

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the difference between [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) and [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) is

> Similar to `mouseover`, `mouseenter` differs in that it doesn't [bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.bubbles) and that it
>   isn't sent when the pointer is moved from one of its descendants'
>   physical space to its own physical space.

If you use `mouseover`, it will bubble up, so the event listener will be triggered on pointed element and its ancestors (your 1st problem).

If you use `mouseenter`, it won't be triggered when the pointer is moved from one of its descendants' physical space to its own physical space (your 2nd problem).

What you need is `mouseover` without bubbling. There's no specific event for that, but you can manually prevent it from bubbling using [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation):

```
$("body").on("mouseover", "*", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var html = $(this).attr("title");
    console.log(html);
    $("#result").text(html);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/C57S2/)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be easily fixed by adding `"[title]"` to the selector.
You can find the working demo [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TEAG9/)

Comment: Sean Madhavan
yes the problem still exist